# Where are deployed cloud computations calculated?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

When an interactive expression is deployed on the cloud, where do the computations take place?

I have some guesses:

1. all possible states are pre-calculated,
2. computations done by the server of the user who is viewing
3. computations done by the server of the user who is created the expression

I tried looking up on the Wolfram documentation, but nothing specific to where the computations get calculated is mentioned.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's actually 4) the computations are done on Wolfram's own servers. This is also why interactive things can be so slow. Admittedly there is a 4.5) if the function may be easily reduced to JS it is and all of that takes place locally.

Comment: Thanks! And if I am not wrong, the storage of variables and intermediate results will also be on those servers and not on User's system?

Comment: You are exactly correct

Answer (score 4):

This CW is to put b2m2a1's comments on record as a answer.

It's actually none of the above three guesses. The computations are done on Wolfram's own servers. This is why interactive things can be so slow. The is the possibility of another computational stage: if the function may be easily reduced to the JavaScript it is, that takes place locally.

Comment: In some very limited cases I believe some computation is done in javascript on the client-side - particularly with interactive Manipulates and so on.